# Boot from DVD from grub?

Tags: grub

I have a laptop with just elementary os on it. I have a windows 10 iso on a dvd that I want to boot off of.

It isn't booting from the DVD-ROM when I restart it just starts up the os.
If I try to enter the bios to adjust boot order it goes into grub which just shows 2 options: elementary os and elementary advanced. I can get a grub command line.
My question is, can I boot from the DVD-ROM in this command line and if so, how?

Comment: Does nobody know the answer to this? I could really use some help